# MySQL Update Not Updating Certain Rows

Tags: mysql

Here is my double-minded query:

```
$Quest = "SELECT * FROM TOAWorkorders";
 $FindTechResult = mysql_query($Quest, $cxn)
        or die ('The easter bunny is watching you' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($FindTechResult))
 {          
      if (strpos($BBT, 0, 3) != 'Sys')
        {

              $IdNum = $row['IdNum'];

              $BBT = $row['BBT'];       
              $BBTArray = explode("-", $BBT);
              $TechNum = $BBTArray["0"];
              $Title = $BBTArray["2"];

             $Name = explode(" ", $BBTArray['1']);
             $FirstName = $Name["0"];
             $LastName = $Name["1"];

                }

echo $TechNum . ' !! ' . $FirstName . ' !! ' . $LastName . ' !! ' . $Title . '<br>';


$Quest = "UPDATE TOAWorkorders SET TechNum = '$TechNum', FirstName = '$FirstName', LastName = '$LastName', Title = '$Title' WHERE IdNum = '$IdNum'";
$result = mysql_query($Quest, $cxn)  or die(mysql_error());   
     }
```

Everything works for about 2/3s of the database.  That leaves 33,000 rows that are not updated.  I cannot find any difference between the data that works and the data that doesn't.

Comment: What does $BBT contain? Your update will only work when you go inside the if as the update requires $IdNUm so I am assuming the problem is with the if statement - please post some values in $BBT which work and some which do not

Comment: Also I thought strpos returned a position or false only? I dont think it would ever return 'Sys'

Comment: BBT is the information that I am given that needs to be digested.  It looks like this:  technum-firstname lastname-title. In that format, the field is totally useless, so I need to chop it down to strings that I can actually select and search.  Nothing is wrong with the two `explode` statements.  They work perfectly through all 109,112 records.  The `update` is another story. A whole 1/3 of the database isn't processed, which amounts to 33,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing an UPDATE, and you say the rest of the code works (meaning, I hope, that you get 109,112 echo'ed results), it must be that the ID isn't being found (WHERE IdNum = '$IdNum').

Try preceding that command with "SELECT COUNT(*) from TOAWorkorders WHERE IdNum = '$IdNum'" and see if you get 33,000 zeros when the program runs. If you do, then you have missing IdNum values in your table.

If you don't, please provide details and I'll let you know.